# segmentation fault while push_back()

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting segmentation fault while running my code, in push_back() function,
My program is given below..

Program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
  private:
    int x, y;
    int * p;
  public:

    Point(int x1, int y1)  {
      x = x1; y = y1;
      *p = 1;
    }

    Point(const Point & p2) {
      x = p2.x;
      y = p2.y;
      *p = 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Point p1(10, 15);
  Point p2 = p1;
  vector<Point> vec;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    vec.push_back(p2);
  }
}
```

Can somebody give the reason for the segmentation fault in the above program ????
Can somebody give the reason for the segmentation fault in the above program ????

Comment: `p` is a pointer, but you don't make it point to a valid object before de-referencing it.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the variable p? If you delete it the crash will go away. You never give p an address so you write the 1 to a random memory location

Comment: just wanted to increment that variable in copy constructor, to keep track of number of copies that are created..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Point(int x1, int y1)  {
  x = x1; y = y1;
  *p = 1;            <<< allocate memory for this pointer first.
}
```

You are de-referencing the uninitialized pointer.

Comment: but why this is running perfectly, if I comment push_back()

Comment: This is just undefined behavior. If you walk through the site you could get enough articles which would refine the meaning of your running. Right now you should make always make sure that you are not de-referencing uninitialized pointer.

Comment: if I am giving p[0] = 1, what will happen ?

Comment: Indirectly you are saying *(p+0) = 1 i.e *p = 1

Answer (score 2):

I recommend making x and y public if you want to modify their values directly; it's better than having getters and setters to do the job. Meanwhile, I propose modifying your code thus:

```
int *p = new int;
```

Doing this will allocate memory for your pointer, and then you can assign values to it. Just out of curiosity, what is the pointer for?

Comment: @ Chris, Vormeph, I was learning c++, I wanted to count no. of copies of the object, in the copy constructor i will increment that variable..

Comment: If you want to do that, you should make p a static variable for it to be global in a class, regardless of instantiation. And everytime the constructor is called you would increment that variable, so you should be using *p++, not *p = 1. The rest is up to you. Currently, the variable will always be instantiated with the class itself; therefore it will always be 1.